# Selenium Frames and SwitchTo Inclusive StaleReferenceException

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, browser

Trying to abstract from Selenium and testing the SAP WebFramework, I found it hard to believe that this wont work.

Currently I start from the root content (default content), enter every frame I discover and do that recursivly. Since you can not easily switch from one child frame to another, I just switch back to the root and switch into the frame using the recorded WebElement path.

This way I can switch from one element to another. (Which works good).

But finding an element (input element in two frames distance form default content) and switch back the element is stale.

Therefore I can not use the reference.

Can it be that the web element itself is a stale reference if the driver is pointing to another document (as a frame represents)? So the web element reference for the frames are not stale since I access them in the same order with the same active frame I retrieved them.

Makes sense but I need someone to verify it for different browser if it is a quirk or if it is a design decision.

I am currently using the IE.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: are you using frame name or xpath ?

Comment: I am using Java and I use the frame web element (which works even accross the frames as long as I use the frame by frame navigation). It seams that I can only access a web element if the current document is the frame containing the element. So I guess xpath doesnt matter.

Answer (score 0):

The current solution that seams to work fine is to actually encapsulate the web element with its frames and provide a facade that tracks the current document location. With this information I can simply invoke and use any web element in any frame at any time and after the usage I switch the document back.

Also I extended the find method to find elements in all frames from the current or the root frame.

It is still an early test but it seams to work as intended. It would be good if selenium could provide something like a frame path and similar features.

Working with the SAP Web Framework which is based on tables and iframes is a pain without this feature.

If this solution works well over the weeks I will update this answer. If someone else has another solution or know a Selenium extension or functionality that helps me doing this, please inform me.